# ¿Como imprimir una matriz en un pdf usando pdfbox? (JAVA)

Tags: java, array, matrices, array-bidimensional, apache-pdfbox

Estoy tratando de generar un pdf usando la librería `pdfbox`, de manera que imprima una matriz así bien ordenada, pero no consigo la forma de hacerlo. Hasta ahora lo único que llevo de código es lo siguiente:

```
public class Reportes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    reportePDF();
}

static double miMatriz[][] = {{1, 2, 2, 3, 5}, {1, 0, -2, 0, 5}, {3, -1, 1, -2, 5}, {4, -3, 0, 2, 5}, {4, 6, 5, 3, 1}};

public static void reportePDF() {
    String contenido0;
    String contenido = "";

    try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
        PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(myPage);

        try (PDPageContentStream cont = new PDPageContentStream(doc, myPage)) {

            cont.beginText();
            cont.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
            cont.setLeading(14.5f);

            cont.newLineAtOffset(25, 700);
            contenido0 = "Estoy tratando de imprimir una matriz";
            cont.showText(contenido0);
            cont.newLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < miMatriz.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < miMatriz[i].length; j++) {
                    contenido += miMatriz[i][j] + " ";
                    cont.showText(contenido);
                    cont.newLine();
                }
            }
            cont.endText();
        }
        doc.save("probando.pdf");
        doc.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su pdf ha sido generado correctamente");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}}
```

Dicho codigo solo me genera el pdf de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual no es de mucha ayuda, espero y alguien pueda ayudarme, de antemano gracias!